# Defining number of "while" loops done?

Tags: python

I am looking to manipulate a string in python, defined as:

```
bin = 5000
```

By halving it for each run of a `while` loop.

The only solution I can think of is defining the number of `while` loops ran as `n` and using the string as `bin*(1/2)**n`

How do I define `n` or should I be looking to other methods?

Comment: When is the loop going to end?  What is the requirement?

Comment: What should the start and end state of your string be? And what does defining bin =5000 (an integer) have to do with it? I'm afraid the question is unclear.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of details. I'm coding in Sikuli so im using `while (image) exists` hence the loop ends when the image no longer exists on screen. @dstudeba

The integer exists as I would like the script to change a text box value (half it every time, starting at 5000) for each loop that occurs as a result of the `(image)`  still existing on screen. @paisanco

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding your question right, you just want the condition for the while loop to be a number that is halves every iteration? If so i posted a example of how you can do that. If not please try to rephrase your question.

```
while bin > 1:
    bin = bin * .5
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly as to what you're asking, but these are two solutions I came up with. If you want to cut a string in half every iteration of a while loop I'd do:

```
string = 'x' * 5000
while len(string) != 1:  # can't be cut into whole number anymore
    string = string[:len(string)/2]
```

If you're trying to simply make a number be cut in half each iteration using a while loop I'd do:

```
number = 5000
while number != 1:  #again, can't be cut into a whole number anymore
    number /= 2
```